# Phonegap not scaling properly between iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, cordova, resolution, scaling

I developed an app for iPad using Phonegap 0.9.6.
Seems to be working fine.

The main element in the app is 768 px wide, so scaling has not been a problem one way or the other.

Now I am experimenting with running the same thing on an iPhone.

I have this meta tag at the top of my html in the 'head' section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

It seems to work fine on the iPhone browser: I can point the browser to my locally-running server, the page gets scaled appropriately so it fits in the iPhone screen.

If I make a 'Home Screen" version of the page so it's more of a WebApp (still not using PhoneGap) I still get scaling, although now it's a little off: the image is a little too wide, a small strip on the right winds up offscreen.

But when I try things in Phonegap I am getting no scaling at all.  The page always shows up at normal resolution, so I am seeing just the top quarter of it.

I have tried all of the following:
* Changing Summary->Devices from iPad to Universal in XCode target settings.
* Mucking with the 'enable display scaling' widget under the 'info' tab of the 'run' item on the scheme for this build.
* Every permutation of trick I can think of for the meta 'viewport' tag: setting min/max scaling, setting initial scale, setting width to fixed numbers, etc.

For that last item, I can see tweaks I make reflected in the Browser on the iPhone (and the HomeScreen version), but the PhoneGap never budges: I always get the same upper-right corner.  I can't seem to make that move at all.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to fit iPhone screen is not to scale and shrink the whole page, but to use scalable html structure and styles for your app, for instance, use `100%` instead of `768px`. You should always avoid scaling the page. Insert this line to the head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

It's better to write same css for both iPhone and iPad, but if you really want to apply different styles for them each, you can use media queries, for example, ipad-specific style is like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css" />
```

You will also want to assign different css files for low-resolution screen and retina screen. Still use media queries.

```
<link href="static/iphone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/retina.css"
    media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to control the scaling trough HTML by putting the following in your PhoneGap.plist file:

EnableViewportScale : YES